# View Google Analytics Data of Multiple Sites?

Tags: google-analytics

On the Google Analytics account I use, we collect analytics for multiple websites. We can see users and sessions for each website, that's great.

So far, every feature of Analytics I've come across only allows me to view information from just **one** site at a time, but now I'd like to see multiple sites.

What we are looking for, is a way to **simultaneously** view the number of users and sessions of all the websites under our account. I have google searched the problem, I've messed with every single setting I can think of. No progress.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Data Studio for this. You can either have separate tables on one page for all of the sites you want to report, or to make it more seamless, make a data blend to get stats from multiple sites with multiple GA accounts into one table

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to create a single view for different trackers in GA.

But you can download data from different trackers to one scheduled report in Google Spreadsheets using Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on

Or create one new tracker and implement on all your websites.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up **cross-domain** measurement.

Cross-domain measurement makes it possible for Analytics to see sessions on two related sites as a single session. This is sometimes called site linking.

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en